# Showing multiple additional rows on table

Tags: javascript, html

I found this coding on the web which I would like to implement on my website but I need it to expand multiple rows when the user clicks on the top row.

With the code as it stands will display both rows but the formatting isn't correct.

```js
function show_hide_row(row) {
  $("#" + row).toggle();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">

  <table border=1 id="table_detail" align=center cellpadding=10>

    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
      <th>Job</th>
    </tr>

    <tr onclick="show_hide_row ('hidden_row1');">
      <td>Ankit</td>
      <td>25</td>
      <td>60000</td>
      <td>Computer Programmer</td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="hidden_row1" class="hidden_row">
      <td colspan=4>Ankit is 25 years old and he is a computer programmer he earns 60000 per month</td>
      <td colspan=4>and he like soccer, tennis and reading</td>
    </tr>

    <tr onclick="show_hide_row   ('hidden_row2');">
      <td>Aarti</td>
      <td>29</td>
      <td>40000</td>
      <td>Web Designer</td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="hidden_row2" class="hidden_row">
      <td colspan=4>Aarti is 29 years old and she is a web designer he earns 40000 per month</td>
      <td colspan=4>and he like eating like a pig</td>
    </tr>

  </table>

</div>
```

Comment: Can you show your attempt(s)?

Comment: if you want them in seperate row then use 2 different `tr`s or if you want one line after another then you put them in one `td` but add a break `br`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *But I need it to expand multiple rows when the user clicks on the top row*

Then you could use common classes instead of `id`'s like the following example shows.

```js
function show_hide_row(row) {
  $("." + row).toggle();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">

  <table border=1 id="table_detail" align=center cellpadding=10>

    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
      <th>Job</th>
    </tr>

    <tr onclick="show_hide_row ('hidden_row1');">
      <td>Ankit</td>
      <td>25</td>
      <td>60000</td>
      <td>Computer Programmer</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="hidden_row hidden_row1">
      <td colspan=4>Ankit is 25 years old and he is a computer programmer he earns 60000 per month</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="hidden_row hidden_row1">
      <td colspan=4>and he like soccer, tennis and reading</td>
    </tr>

    <tr onclick="show_hide_row('hidden_row2');">
      <td>Aarti</td>
      <td>29</td>
      <td>40000</td>
      <td>Web Designer</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="hidden_row hidden_row2">
      <td colspan=4>Aarti is 29 years old and she is a web designer he earns 40000 per month</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="hidden_row hidden_row2">
      <td colspan=4>and he like eating like a pig</td>
    </tr>

  </table>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have the `colspan` set to `4` instead of `2` so it takes up 8 columns instead of 4 in total.

```
<tr id="hidden_row1" class="hidden_row">
  <td colspan=2>Ankit is 25 years old and he is a computer programmer he earns 60000 per month</td>
  <td colspan=2>and he like soccer, tennis and reading</td>
</tr>
```

and

```
<tr id="hidden_row2" class="hidden_row">
  <td colspan=2>Aarti is 29 years old and she is a web designer he earns 40000 per month</td>
  <td colspan=2>and he like eating like a pig</td>
</tr>
```